# Flask + SQLAlchemy: Create index column for table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having difficulty creating an index for a table in sqlite3 database with SQLALchemy. Each time a row is added to the database through celery's periodic task, the row will be indexed.

Perhaps my understanding is flawed.. I thought that `db.Index('scheduleId', Schedule.taskId)` automatically creates a new 'scheduleId' column with value of 1 once the first row of data hits the database?

**app/model.py**

```
class Schedule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    taskId = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Schedule, self).__init__(**kwargs)

db.Index('scheduleId', Schedule.taskId)
```

**app/tasks/test.py**

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*"), bind=True)
def periodic_run_get_manifest(self):
    with app.app_context():
        task_id = self.request.id
        s = Schedule()
        s.taskId = task_id
        db.session.add(s)
        db.session.commit()
        rowId = db.session.query(Schedule).order_by(Schedule.scheduleId.desc()).first()
```

When the periodic tasks runs, i get the below error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Schedule' has no attribute 'scheduleId'

Comment: where is `scheduleId` column? I see only `taskId`. you try to call to undefined model property.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Wouldn't "db.Index('scheduleId', Schedule.taskId)" create it? Or you mean i have to state it as "scheduleId = db.Column(dg.Integer, index=True, unique=True)"? But then it would throw an error when i insert the record to database because i wouldn't know the scheduleId. I want scheduleId to automatically increase each time a record hits the database.

Comment: Index is not column. replace `Schedule.scheduleId.desc()` to `Schedule.taskId.desc()`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class model

```
class Schedule(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'schedule'
        taskId = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
        scheduleId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # will create index and autoincrement both
```

[Autoincrement Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#auto-increment-behavior)

[Index Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#indexes)

Comment: Thanks! but seems that if i insert a record to database without specifying 'scheduleId', the column will be left blank.

Comment: I am wondering if it is creating autoincrement for your other column as well. try defining `autoincrement=False` for other field and try again.

Comment: This is bizarre. I know there can be issues if there are two autoincrements in a table. Can you show the table schema actually created? Does it contain autoincrement attribute?

Comment: @mad_1. Hi, the column i want to auto-increment on (scheduleId), should be the primary key. I changed to  "scheduleId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True) , taskId = db.Column(db.String(50))". then dropped and created all the tables and now it works. thanks!

Comment: @mad_1 Do you want to edit your answer for the primary key to be 'scheduleId' so that i can mark it as correct?